# XUL tabbox tabs scrolling

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, xul

The same question has been asked [in the Mozillazine forums earlier](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1317495). Borrowing his description:

I'm developing an extension for Firefox and have a great problem. I've got lots of tabs in my extension and in case of small size windows some of the tabs are not visible. That's why I want to put scrollbars and I can't succeed.

Here is my code

```xml
<tabbox flex="1">
<tabs>
<arrowscrollbox allowevents="true" flex="1" class="tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox" orient="horizontal">
<tab id="tab_1" label="Tab 1"/>
<tab id="tab_2" label="Tab 2"/>
...
<tab id="tab_9" label="Tab 9"/>
</arrowscrollbox>
</tabs>
<tabpanels flex="1">
<tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 1 content</tabpanel>  
<tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 2 content</tabpanel>  
...
<tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 9 content</tabpanel>  
</tabpanels>
</tabbox>
```

In this case scrolling does work on tabs but clicking on the tab does nothing, thus the correspondent tab content is not displayed.
If I remove the arrowscrollbox element from the tabs element, I get no scroll and some of tabs are not visible.

So can anyone suggest me a way when I will have both scrolling and properly working tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<tab>` tags have to be direct clildren of the `<tabs>` tag, otherwise it won't work. The `<tabs>` tag doesn't have to be a direct child of the `<tabbox>` tag however so you can put the `<arrowscrollbox>` tag in between. This way it works:

```xml
<tabbox flex="1">
  <arrowscrollbox allowevents="true" class="tabbrowser-arrowscrollbox" orient="horizontal">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tab_1" label="Tab 1"/>
      <tab id="tab_2" label="Tab 2"/>
      ...
      <tab id="tab_9" label="Tab 9"/>
    </tabs>
  </arrowscrollbox>
  <tabpanels flex="1">
    <tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 1 content</tabpanel>
    <tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 2 content</tabpanel>
    ...
    <tabpanel flex="1" orient="vertical" >Tab 9 content</tabpanel>
  </tabpanels>
</tabbox>
```

Comment: Thank you! additionally I had to add <tabs style="overflow:hidden"> for the arrows to show